# Web browser forces https after using and then removing django-secure

Tags: django, security, browser, https

(Using Windows 7, Python 3.4, and Django 1.6, using virtualenv)

Hey, all. I tried using django-secure to force https and ssl on my django project. Then I decided I didn't want it until I actually put the site online, because I didn't have a security certificate, so I couldn't even try out the site on my computer. After removing the django-secure code from my settings, uninstalling django-secure using pip, and restarting my computer, any browser I visited the page with while using django-secure forces https whenever I run that particular django project, but not on other projects. Uninstalling and reinstalling worked for Safari and Firefox, but not for Chrome. I couldn't uninstall Internet Explorer or Opera using the Control Panel, so I thought it might be easier just to change some settings in the browsers, if I knew how to do that. Does anyone know how I can make Chrome not force https on my project and how to do that with Opera and IE without uninstalling them?

I think the above details could lead to finding the answer, but if you want it, here's my detailed description of what I did in what order:

I followed the installation and usage instructions at https://github.com/carljm/django-secure, up through "Set the SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS setting to an integer number of seconds and SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS to True, if you want to use HTTP Strict Transport Security." I then tried it out on chrome and found out I needed a security certificate, and decided I'd rather wait till I actually put the website online. So I removed the parts of the settings file that I had added following the django-secure instructions, stopped and restarted my local server, opened it on chrome, and found that it forced https, but only for that particular django project. I then used pip to uninstall django-secure, but chrome still forced https. I tried it on firefox, ie, opera, and safari, and had no problem. I then restarted my computer, but that didn't solve the problem. So I reinstalled django-secure using pip, and repeated the steps I had followed from the django-secure instructions. I then ran it on safari and ie, removed those lines from settings, and reran it, and they continued to force https on that django project. I repeated the process with Opera and Firefox, and had the same problem. Uninstalling and reinstalling Safari and Firefox fixed the problem in those browsers. It didn't fix the problem in Chrome. I couldn't uninstall Opera or IE from the control panel, so I think I'll just wait till I find out another way of fixing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear your browser cache.

Django-secure sends a `HttpResponsePermanentRedirect` (302 status code) to the secure version of the page, so your browser will cache the response and always redirect you to the https version.

Comment: @JohnL. You're welcome. If you accept my answer, others can easily see that this question has been answered.